# remove whitespace from piped output

Tags: bash, grep, zsh

In a textfile i have some tags with the notation `:foo`. To get an overview of my tags in the file, I want to get a listing of all this tags.

This is done via

```
grep -o -e ":[a-z]*\( \|$\)" file.txt | sort |  uniq
```

Now I get duplicates because of the whitespace or newline character at the end.

```
:movie  <-- only newline
:movie  <-- whitespace and newline
:read
:read
```

I want to avoid the duplicates. But I could not figure out how. I tried with `| tr -d '[:space:]'`, but this leads only to a concatenation of all pipe output...

Example of the file.txt

```
Avengers: Infinity War :movie
Yojimbo 1961 :movie nippon
```

Comment: Is that `:movie nippon` a tag, ie. there can be spaces in them or is that 2 tags? Please, post a proper sample with expected output.

Comment: @JamesBrown tags are one word, no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some test lines (there is a space after the first `:space`, you can see it if you highlight the data with your mouse):

```
$ cat file
with :space 
with :space too
without :space
test: this
```

With `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ grep -o ":[a-z]\+" file | sort | uniq 
:space
```

With awk (well, gawk and mawk at least):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[" FS "|" RS "]+"}/:[a-z]/&&!a[$0]++' file
:space
```

Each word is its own record and we pick the first instance of every colon-starting word. `RS="[" FS "|" RS "]+"` could be written otherwise but it is in this form to emphasize any combination of `FS` and `RS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl regexp and word matching:

```
grep -oP ':\w+' file.txt | sort |  uniq
```

or, just match non-space characters:

```
grep -o ':[^ ]*' file.txt | sort |  uniq
```

Comment: Your answer look as well nice, but had some issues on osx. Perl regex is not available and the match of none space characters found more matches then I need. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the sample Input_file so couldn't test it as well as I don't have zsh with me. Try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/:[a-z]*/{sub(/ +$/,"");} !a[$0]++' Input_file | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed

```
sed 's/.*\(:[a-z]*\).*/\1/' file.txt | sort | uniq
```